# Какой оптимальный размер и разрешение в ширину изображения должны быть, чтобы изображение весило мало, но качество было на уровне "хорошо"?

Tags: android, изображения

Не хотелось бы загружать большие по размеру изображения на сервер. Возможно, для изображений есть приблизительные размеры в пикселях, чтобы они выглядели хорошо(качественно) в Android и с минимальным размером. С учетом того, что изображения отображаются во всю ширину экрана.

Сейчас мое изображение 170 кБ с разрешением 342 х 414 пикселей. Это нормально? Я хотела бы максимально уменьшить размер, но в то же время получить хорошее качество изображения в Android.

Хотелось бы услышать ваши советы.

Comment: Представления о том, что хорошо, а что не очень, конечно, субъективны, но мне кажется, что для качественного изображения количество пикселей картинки не должно быть меньше, чем количество пикселей той области экрана, в которой вы ее показываете

Comment: @avp я думаю, что тут нужно учитывать не только размер картинки, но и степень ее сжатия.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите получить максимальное качество с минимальными затратами памяти - придется использовать векторную графику.

Если это затруднительно, то тут есть следующий момент. Т.к. количество пикселей на единицу площади у разных устройств отличается в разы, появляется некоторый scale, который сообщает о том насколько крупнее должно быть чтобы остаться того же физического размера. На примере: на планшете в 7 дюймов диагонали и с разрешением в 1024x600 ваша картинка будет физически занимать место примерно 5,7х6,9 см. На fullHD 5 дюймовом телефоне займет 1,9х2,34. скалирование линейных размеров, как видите, примерно в 3 раза. Чтобы на разных устройствах картинки занимали одинаковый физический размер, этот scale вшили в оболочку, для каждого устройства он свой из следующих: ldpi 0,75x; mdpi 1x; hdpi 1,5x; xhdpi 2,0x; xxhdpi 3,0x; xxxhdpi 4,0x

И чтобы ваше приложение имело адекватный внешний вид все ваши растровые изображения должны быть сохранены под каждый из этих скейлов. Не самый приятный вариант, но действительно необходимый

Поподробнее почитать можно [тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support) и [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities). Ну и немного [по-русски](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/design/basic.php)

Все это я тут развел потому, что одной текущей картинкой вы сыты не будете, к сожалению. А когда ваша программа считывает файл, скажем, из jpeg, она преобразует его в рисунок без сжатия и именно так и хранит. Потому если вы сделаете мипмапы под все размеры, то устройство с меньшей плотностью экрана загрузит меньшую по размерам картинку, которая займет пропорционально меньший объем оперативной памяти. Ну, или попробуйте перейти на вектор, если изображение не слишком сложное

Comment: Дело в том, что я загружаю изображение на сервер в единственном числе, заранее отредактировав в Adobe PS. И мне нужно найти "золотую" середину между размером изображения и качеством. Возможно, стоит добавить изображения, как вы писали, под каждый размер экрана на сервер и уже с помощью дополнительных проверок скачивать изображение для конкретного экрана. Вариант ли это? Надеюсь, вы ответите на этот вопрос.

Comment: Вполне себе вариант. В коде легко можно получить скейл из объекта DisplayMetrics, и либо параметром шлите в запросе, чтобы сервер обработал его и выдал нужную картинку, либо проименуйте их по разному и определяйте какую выкачивать в приложении