# Как сделать background активити одинаковым. (в том плане чтобы он не искажался на разных размерах) Android-studio

Tags: java, android

Как сделать background активити одинаковым ? (в том плане чтобы он не искажался на разных размерах)
small,
large,
xlarge.

Если что эти файлы  у меня присутствует (small,
large, xlarge.)  на них тоже самая картинка но другие размеры шрифтов.

Устанавливаю background так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/nameless1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Я что-то слышал по 9.patch
но не понимаю как там всё настроить?

Любая информация будет полезна.

Если что вот фото...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже это тоже самое: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/984983/238266

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно в вашем случае вам не поможет 9. Я бы предложил здесь сделать изображение, включающую одну единственную клеточку, и мастить ее мозаикой

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/cell_image"
        android:tileMode="repeat" /> //вместо repeat можно попробовать mirror, может даст лучший эффект
```

Для адекватного размера клеточек придется сделать кучу этих изображений клеточки с разным разрешением, по [ссылке в комментах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/984983/238266) я как раз об этом говорил

Answer (score 0):

В общем, что нужно сделать. Создать четыре файла c какими разрешениями я использую Photoshop
( Добавить туда вашу фотку " background")

xhdpi 640 *960 px

hdpi 480*800  px

mdpi 320*480  px

ldpi 240*320 px

Ctrl+c  Ctrl+v

Потом добавить  всё в папку (mipmap)

Программа предложит  выбрать нужный размер (К примеру если вы добавляете xhdpi 640 *960 )
то устанавливаете xhdpi.
как соответственно для всех файлов.

Да Самое главное без этого работать не будет!!!!!
Все фотографии должны быть  с одним именем!!(Но при этом  с разными разрешениями)

И устанавливайте в своем Activity  ( задний фон    android:background="@mipmap/nameless")