# Оптимальное разрешение текстуры для маркера

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, каких размеров лучше сделать текстурки для маркеров на гугл карте, если они лежат в отдельном каталоге на диске? 
Я делаю 85х85 пикселей под разрешение экрана 1280х720, получается нормально. Но уже выпускают новые смартфоны с разрешением 3840x2160, и это не предел наверно, то там же мои текстурки будут уже микроскопическими?

Answer (score 0):

[Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/984913/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7/984983#984983) я расписывал как работают ваши картинки на разных плотностях экрана. Именно плотности, потому что ваша картинка 85х85 на дисплее 1280х720 восьмидюймового планшета будут выглядеть огромными. разрешение малоинтересны разработчику, dp наше все :)

Comment: Так у меня по задумке свои иконки добавляет сам пользователь в каталог Icons, который создается.. Они же имеют разрешение в пикселях..

Comment: Этого не было в вопросе, уточняйте такие вещи. Ваш пользователь живет на одном устройстве. Потому вы можете определить размер иконки для его устройства и сохранять именно его. Допустим, на х1 скейле вас устраивает 85х85. Тогда если у юзера скей х2 - сохраняете иконку 170х170. Скейл устройства можно получить из объекта DisplayMetrics. Единственное может всякие бэкаперы могу перенести ваши данные на другое устройства, и как тогда быть не могу сказать, но это крайне редкое явление